# Компиляции под ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, unix, компиляция

Я начал читать книгу "UNIX. Профессиональное программирование" и столкнулся с одной непонятной вещью уже с первого листинга.
Вот исходник основной программы, который находится в `/home/***/Programming_UNIX/myls/`:

```
//myls.c
#include "apue.h"  <-------
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    
    if(argc != 2)
        err_quit("Использование: ls имя_каталога");
        
    if((dp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
        err_sys("Невозможно открыть %s", argv[1]);
    while((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
    
    closedir(dp);
    exit(0);
}
```

И есть заголовочный apue.h и исходный файл error.c, которые лежат в родительском каталоге по отношению к основной программе. Автор пишет, что скомпилировать основную программу можно с помощью `cc myls.c`, но это невозможно, даже если переместить заголовочный файл с error.c в одну директорию с основной программой (myls.c). Я скомпилировал вот так `gcc -I/home/***/Programming_UNIX/ ../error.c myls.c`. Может я что-то не знаю и можно скомпилировать программу как написал автор?

Comment: `error.c` это реализация `apue.h`?

Comment: Вы все правильно сделали. А кто автор книжки?

Comment: @avp, думаю, Стивенс...

Comment: @test_, APUE всё же рассчитывает, что у читателя есть базовые навыки обращения с компилятором и прочими инструментами тулчейна, так что не заостряет на этом внимания... в общем можно оставить и как ты сделал, хотя там скорее подразумевается, что нужно собрать статическую библиотеку и подключать её к примерам...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, бегло глянул pdf-ку. Думаю, вы правы. Автор просто оставляет читателю свободу в организации кода и инструментов сборки. Т.е. `cc myls.c` это не дословная инструкция по компиляции, а абстрактный пример

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: На юниксе, включкая упоминаемый Sun, компилятор был действительно `сс`, существовал так же oracle-ский `lcc` ( а также это псевдонимы gcc на "Эльбрусах"), на ранних Линуксах это был псевдоним.